# jQuery: Display button only when attachment is available

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `li` list of attachment fields where `Delete` and `Upload` buttons are present too.

I want to `hide /show` the buttons only when respective `attachment` is uploaded in the list.

Currently, I have done it for One input field.

Any help/suggestion on how can I improve it.

**Markup**

```
<div class="input-wrapper">
    /* Attachment field */
</div>

<div class="delete-button">
    <div class="delete-button-row">
        <button class="button-sm" type="button" id="del_file" disabled />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="upload-button">
    <div class="upload-button-row">
        <button class="button-upload-sm" type="button" id="" disabled />
    </div>
</div>
```

---

**code**

```
$('button:button').attr('disabled',false);
$('#del_file').attr('disabled',false);
```

Thanks

Comment: add your markup too

Comment: @NithinChandran updated

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is to show/hide buttons when a file is uploaded.

There are two ways a web page can upload a file -

1. Via form submission
2. Via manual file reading and making an ajax remote request

In the first case, all you can know during the time of attachment selection is if a file is selected by the user. For this, you need to hook up an event listener to your file upload (input file) elements.

```
$('#myFileUUupload').on('change', (e) => {

    //Show your buttons here
})
```

In the second case, you will have to disable the buttons after you receive your ajax response.

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "example.com/upload",
     success: function (data) {
         //Show your buttons here
})
```

---

If your question is about hiding and showing elements, you can use `hide()` and `show()`  methods of Jquery

```
$('button:button').hide();
$('button:button').show();
```

Comment: it should be hidden before hand. It can only be shown when any file is uploaded .